# Variable is not being replaced in ASPX

Tags: asp.net

I have 2 ASPX files:

In A.aspx:

```
<%
string user = "<a href=\"b.aspx?id=<%=dz_now%>\">in A.aspx.cs</a>";
Response.Write(user);
%>
```

In B.aspx.cs

```
string id = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
​Response.Write(id);
```

When I run `A.aspx` and click on the link, the value of `id` from `B.aspx` is "`<%=dz_now%>`".

Why?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `<%=variable %>` does not work within server side code.  You need to add the strings together like this:

```
string user = "<a href=\"b.aspx?id=" + dz_now + "\">in A.aspx.cs</a>";
```